# Remove specific values in a dataframe based on whether or not they're in an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, one of which is a comma separated list of values:

```
A  1,2,3,4,6

B  1,5,6,7

C  1,3,2,8,9,7

D  1,3,6,8
```

I also have an array: `[2,3,9]`

And I'd like to end up with the same dataframe, transformed in such a way that values not in the array are filtered out. Eg:

```
A  2,3

B  

C  3,2,9

D  3
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  I've had a look around but have hit a bit of a wall.

Comment: What's a "comma separated list"? A string?

Answer (score 0):

***Setup***

```
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'col2': ['1,2,3,4,6', '1,5,6,7', '1,3,2,8,9,7', '1,3,6,8']
})

good = [str(i) for i in [2,3,9]]
```

---

We can use a regular expression and `re.findall` to extract all acceptable values, we just have to assert that the matches don't directly follow or precede a digit, so that we don't match digits in the middle of another number:

```
rgx = '(?<!\d)({})(?!\d)'.format('|'.join(good))

df.assign(out=[','.join(re.findall(rgx, row)) for row in df.col2])
```

```
  col1         col2    out
0    A    1,2,3,4,6    2,3
1    B      1,5,6,7
2    C  1,3,2,8,9,7  3,2,9
3    D      1,3,6,8      3
```

---

***Regex Explanation***

```
(?<!                 # Negative lookbehind
  \d                 # Asserts previous character is *not* a digit
)           
(                    # Matching group
  2|3|9              # Matches either 2 or 3 or 9
) 
(?!                  # Negative lookahead
  \d                 # Asserts the following character is *not* a digit
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The apply-method provides a very readable solution in my opinion.

```
allowed = [2, 3, 9]
allowed_string = [str(x) for x in allowed]
df[1] = df[1].str.split(',')
df[1] = df[1].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y in allowed_string])
```

Output:

```
   0          1
0  A     [2, 3]
1  B         []
2  C  [3, 2, 9]
3  D        [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filer the column values using isin() method. see below example.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':[1,2,3,4,6],
        'B':[1,5,6,7],
        'C':[1,3,2,8,9,7],
        'D':[1,3,6,8]}

allow_list = [2,3,9]    #list of allowed elements

df = pd.concat([pd.Series(val, name=key) for key, val in data.items()], axis=1)

df1=df[df[df.columns].isin(allow_list)]    #provide list of allowed elements as parameter in isin method
df1.dropna(how='all',inplace=True)    #remove rows which are all NaN
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     A    C   B    D
1  2.0  3.0 NaN  3.0
2  3.0  2.0 NaN  NaN
4  NaN  9.0 NaN  NaN
```